# Does a PCIe to dual mini-PCIe adapter exist?

Tags: pci-express

I'm planning to make a home server that would serve as NAS, router and *Wi-Fi access point*. It should be small, so I choose mini-ITX form-factor which often has only one PCIe slot. I want a powerfull but compact wireless solution - 802.11abgn / *dual band* / 3x3 RxTx.
As far as I know single cards can't work in the AP mode in two bands simultaneously. It requires two cards. Many of such cards made in the mini-PCIe format.
And finally, the main goal: how to install two mini-PCIe cards in the one PCIe slot?

I need a PCIe to *dual* mini-PCIe adapter. Is such thing exist? I would be glad to see links to some examples of such products.

Found many 1-to-1 adapters, but I have only one PCIe slot available and I need to instal two mini-PCIe cards. There are a bit of *PCI/104-Express* to dual mini-PCIe adapters but I want a less complicated solution if it exists.

I found a mini-PCIe to dual mini-PCIe extender. It's based on the [PEX8603](http://www.plxtech.com/products/expresslane/pex8603) commutator from the PLX Technology. How much PCIe bandwidth would be affected? Is it a good solution?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.connecttech.com%2Fpdf%2FCTI-X-PCIe-Singe-Dual-MiniPCIe-Card.pdf&ei=coZYUqHoH4yo0wWAroH4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHzbGtEymU1xPrOCXD2cHT-_zPhmQ&bvm=bv.53899372,d.d2k&cad=rja). Not sure how less complicated you want this to be - Just install the board and you should be set.

Comment: It's PCIe/104-Express card, not conventional PCIe. It could be used with the special PCIe to PCIe/104-Express adapter, but I want a more simple solution, if possible.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a USB version of one of the mini-PCIe cards you are trying to use?

Comment: Please, do not deviate from the subject, I know workarounds.

Comment: The comment towards @ultrasawblade seems a little rude... Helping sometimes involves alternatives afterall.

Comment: Sorry guys, but here is not a forum, we need exact answers more or less, if author specifically doesn't ask for alternatives.

Comment: We don't do product recommendations - and yes, in many cases, the solution to the real problem may not be what you're expecting, since the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) does exist

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, should I delete my question?

Comment: I do think it looks like a product recommendation. That said, most of the things you'd find in mini pci-e arn't very bandwidth intensive (unless you're planning on running, say, a pair of mini pci-e ssds in raid), so it ought to work. This seems like an odd scenario. You might be able edit to reframe the question in the context of your extender, and the specific mini pci-e cards you intend to use - as things are your question revolves around how you want to solve your problem, rather than what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hare are a couple of options:

http://www.amfeltec.com/products/flexible-x1pcie-to-3minipcie-splitter.php

http://www.amfeltec.com/products/flexible-minipcie-splitter2.php